# Javafx and the Observer pattern - updating a UI

Tags: javafx

I am trying to implement the Observer pattern in a JavaFx application. I've never asked a question here but this is driving me a bit crazy.

Essentially I'm trying to use the Observer pattern to monitor a class that's parsing a file of phone numbers, and update the UI automatically as the file is parsed.

Before I get to my questions, here is my code:

**Abstract class Observer.java**

```
public abstract class Observer 
{
   public PhoneBook numbers;

   public abstract void update();
}
```

I have a class that implements this:

```
public class PhoneBookObserver extends Observer {

    public PhoneBookObserver(PhoneBook numbers)
    {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.numbers.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update()
    {
        System.out.println(""NUMBER - : " + numbers.GetNumbers());

    }
}
```

In the class doing the parsing, I've created a new PhoneBookObserver

```
public PhoneBook ParsePhoneBook() 
{   
    PhoneBook nums= new PhoneBook();
    PhoneBookObserver p = new PhoneBookObserver(nums);

    // ... Parsing of file - works fine

   return nums;
}
```

Currently this runs and my println from update() in PhoneBookObserver is output.

My questions are:

- Can the update method of PhoneBookObserver update my UI for me? How would it access JavaFx elements in my controller?
- Can I just make my controller an observer, override update() and use that to update my UI elements from within my controller? Is that bad?

Comment: Sort of an aside: [JavaFX properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) essentially already implement the observer pattern for you. Why not just use those and avoid reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Where would I add the listeners? In initialize?

Comment: Usually, yes. It depends on how you set things up, but that would be the obvious choice in most scenarios. (A listener is just an observable in the observer pattern terminology. The JavaFX properties, or observable lists, are the observables.)

Comment: What if I did want to update my UI from update() in PhoneBookObserver, is that possible?

Comment: I would either implement `PhoneBookObserver` as an inner class in the controller, or (equivalently) provide a top-level implementation that had a reference to the controller. TBH, I would probably remove the `numbers` field from `Observer` - it's not really serving any purpose there since `update()` doesn't refer to it. Then you can make `Observer` an interface. And then you can just pass a lambda expression to `PhoneBook.attach(...)`, and now it's trivial to create an implementation directly in the controller...

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I might use the inner class method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly answer your question, I would probably implement the `Observer` as an inner class in the controller. Then it has access to everything in the controller.

Assuming here `PhoneBook` defines a method of the form

```
public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() ;
```

then you could do:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList ;

    private PhoneBook numbers = new PhoneBook() ; // or initialize from elsewhere

    public void initialize() {
        numbers.attach(new PhoneBookObserver(numbers));
        // ...
    }

    private class PhoneBookObserver extends Observer {

        PhoneBookObserver(PhoneBook numbers) {
            this.numbers = numbers ;
        }

        @Override
        public void update() {
            phoneNumberList.getItems().setAll(numbers.getPhoneNumbers());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in

```
public abstract class Observer 
{
   public PhoneBook numbers;

   public abstract void update();
}
```

the field `numbers` really serves no purpose, as the only method doesn't use it. So you could remove it (subclasses can define such a field if they need). Then you may as well make it an interface, and since it only has one method, it's a `@FunctionalInterface`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Observer {
    public void update() ;
}
```

and now it can be implemented with a lambda expression, so the implementation is so thin that you basically stop having any issues with "accessing the UI":

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList ;

    private PhoneBook numbers = new PhoneBook() ; // or initialize from elsewhere

    public void initialize() {
        numbers.attach(() -> phoneNumberList.getItems().setAll(numbers.getPhoneNumbers());
        // ...
    }

}
```

Finally, note that [JavaFX Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) and observable lists basically already provide an implementation of the observer pattern, so you're pretty much reinventing the wheel here. You could just have

```
public class PhoneBook {

    private final ObservableList<PhoneNumber> numbers;

    public ObservableList<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return numbers ;
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList ;

    private PhoneBook numbers = new PhoneBook() ; // or initialize from elsewhere

    public void initialize() {
        phoneNumberList.setItems(numbers.getPhoneNumbers());
    }

}
```

and the list view will observe the (already-observable) list of numbers for you. There is no real need for your `Observer` or `PhoneBookObserver`.

Comment: Will give this a try, but in the initialize method, won't I need to pass a PhoneBook object in numbers.attach(new PhoneBookObserver());?

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed that. (I was already of the mindset that this was redundant :).)

Comment: I've tried this and the update() method in PhoneBookObserver never gets triggered, I've also added a println which is not output.

Comment: I assume the parser has he same instance of `PhoneBook` that the controller is using?

Comment: Got it solved, thank you. Going to mark this as the answer.